# Trigger.io logging config error

Tags: trigger.io

I have added the following to my `config.json` as per the [Trigger.io documentation](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/logging.html):

```
"modules": {
    "logging": {
        "level": ["DEBUG", "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRITICAL"]
    }
}
```

When I run `forge build` I get the following error:

```
[  ERROR] Forge API call to app/fe491ecee6fb11e19ada12313d1adcbe/template went wrong: Value [u'DEBUG', u'INFO', u'WARNING', u'ERROR', u'CRITICAL'] for field 'level' is not of type string
```

Is the documentation wrong or am I misreading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose one of the options of the array given in the docs, for example:

```
"modules": {
    "logging": {
        "level": "DEBUG"
    }
}
```